# Timed trigger for GPIO input

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3b+, rpi.gpio

I'm running a raspberry pi system that records fish as they swim passed an IR break beam sensor at a fish ladder. So far the system works well but I'm trying to cut down some of the false triggers. There aren't many but I believe that by making it so that video will only begin recording after the beam has been broken for 1-2 seconds instead of starting instantaneously upon the beam breaking it will help to trim them down. Here is my code:

```py
# Imports
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime 
import logging

# Variables
camera = PiCamera()
BEAM_PIN = 4                                # Pin we are using to read the IR break beam switch
log_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%y')
#create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # log all escalated at and above DEBUG

# Setup the GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                 # GPIO layout mode      
GPIO.setup(BEAM_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #Setup the gpio pin we are reading from as a pullup input

# Loop checking the switch
while True:
    # Read the switch value
    input = GPIO.input(BEAM_PIN)

    # If the GPIO reading goes from high to low, record for 30 secs
    if input != 1:
        #define time format for filenames and log output
        now = time.localtime(time.time())      #Variable plugged into asci time to allow for readable date print out 
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%y_%H%M%S") #Variable to update name of video files with current date and time
        #add a file handler
        hdlr = logging.FileHandler('/media/pi/F8AF-129D/log_files/{}.log'.format(log_time))
        # create a formatter and set the formatter for the handler
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        #add the handler to the logger
        logger.addHandler(hdlr)
        logger.info('Lamprey Detected!')
        logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
        camera.start_recording('/media/pi/F8AF-129D/videos/{}.h264'.format(timestamp)) #Recording video file to Lexar thumb drive
        camera.wait_recording(30)
        camera.stop_recording()
        time.sleep(0.05) #Debounce wait
```

I'm having a hard time finding documentation about how to implement this change into the code. I get that I need to alter the if statement in the loop but I'm not sure of the proper syntax to get where I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you've probably already tried this, but my first instinct is just to add a sleep time before the camera starts i.e:

```
logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
time.sleep(2) #Camera delay, change 2 to whatever you want the delay to be
camera.start_recording('/media/pi/F8AF-129D/videos/{}.h264'.format(timestamp))
```

Comment: That won't work.  Merely sleeping for a second after the instant of beam break doesn't check that the beam has been broken continuously for a second.

Comment: OK I see, so you need to do a count of how long  the beam break is, then if it meets the criteria, start recording?